# Aurelia compose ViewModel-less

Tags: aurelia-templating

Trying to get the Aurelia compose ViewModel-less working and having some issues.

I was having problems in my project so to test I cloned the [skeleton-typescript](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript) project.
I created a test.html page within the src directory with the following contents `<template><div>Hi I'm a test message</div></template>`.
Then, within the welcome.html page I added the following before the submit button
`<template><compose view="./test.html"></compose></template>`.

It doesn't display so wondering if I'm doing something wrong (according to the docs this is how it's done) or is there an issue with aurelia's [templating-resources](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources)?

I asked on Aurelia's Gitter channel but didn't get a reply and I don't want to raise an issue with the templating-resources in case it's something stupid I'm doing so thought I would ask here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there. With just a couple of tweaks, this should work. The steps required to add a dynamically composed view in Aurelia are as follows:

**Creating a dynamic view**

Create the HTML template. In this case you need to create your `test.html` template as shown in the below snippet.

**test.html**

`<template>
    <div>Hi I'm a test message</div>
</template>`

**Compose the view into your parent component**

After you've created the view, you need to compose it into the parent component using the `<compose>` custom element provided by the Aurelia framework. In your case, you'll need to make the below alteration to your `<welcome>` view template:

```html
<template>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <h2>${heading}</h2>
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="submit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fn">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bind="firstName" class="form-control" 
            id="fn" placeholder="first name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bind="lastName" class="form-control" id="ln" placeholder="last name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <p class="help-block">${fullName | upper}</p>
      </div>
      <compose view="./test.html"></compose>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>
```

After doing this, your view should include the new composed in HTML only custom element as shown in this screengrab.

[image]

Comment: Sean, you're a star mate. I knew I was doing something stupid but couldn't see it for looking!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, `compose` caught me out the first time I used it as well :D